# Regex in python: replace multiple occurrences of comma between double quotes

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a way to replace all commas in csv file that occur between two double quotes with pipes using python.

Given such input:

`abc,def,"ghi,jkl,mno",pqr,stu`

I would like to get:

`abc,def,"ghi|jkl|mno",pqr,stu`

I have tried to use positive lookarounds with something similar to:

`(?<=\")(this here should match every comma)(?=\")` but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not read this string as is with `csv` parser and then just `replace(',', '|')`? BTW, it is not a case when you may use lookarounds, you need to match valid double quoted fields, and it might not be as easy as `"[^"]+"`. To do that properly, you should know how double quotes inside fields are escaped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use re.sub with anonym or lambda function in the replacement part.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'abc,def,"ghi,jkl,mno",pqr,stu'
>>> re.sub(r'"[^"]+"', lambda x: x.group().replace(',', '|'), s)
'abc,def,"ghi|jkl|mno",pqr,stu'
```

Note: this won't handle escaped quotes and assume all the double quotes are properly balanced.

Comment: The `r'"[^"]+"'` solution does not account for literal `"` inside field values.

Comment: Double quotes will always be balanced and never escaped.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep.. added note..

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work nicely. I didn't know about the lambda syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

Could a simpler approach like this work for you:

```
string = 'abc,def,"ghi|jkl|mno",pqr,stu'
string_splited = string.split('"')
string_splited[1] = string_splited[1].replace(',', '|')
```

That would give you a list:

```
>>> string_splited
['abc,def,', 'ghi|jkl|mno', ',pqr,stu']
```

That you could reassemble

```
>>> '"'.join(string_splited)
'abc,def,"ghi|jkl|mno",pqr,stu'
```

Comment: I have a huge csv file, I'd like to avoid doing per-newline split. Regex solution is also much shorter :)